# ¿Por qué no se alteran mis estilos para la clase .header__links?

Tags: html, css, scss

He puesto la clase en todos lados y no recibe cambios.

Toda la sintaxis parece estar bien. Quiero modificar los enlaces y simplemente no lo hacen, aunque estén en `style.css`.

Código fuente del fichero `index.html`: [github.com](https://github.com/GuillermoCruz93/Easybank_landing_page/blob/master/index.html)

Código fuente del fichero `style.css`: [github.com](https://github.com/GuillermoCruz93/Easybank_landing_page/blob/master/app/scss/style.css)

Enlace al repositorio: [github.com](https://github.com/GuillermoCruz93/Easybank_landing_page)

Comment: Coloca un [repro] _en la pregunta_, con el botón que indica `{}`, o si quieres crear un snippet, con `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a la comunidad.

Puedes probar las siguientes soluciones:

1. Elimina la barra horizontal de la [línea 13](https://github.com/GuillermoCruz93/Easybank_landing_page/blob/master/index.html#L13) al inicio del valor del atributo `href`, quedando como `app/scss/style.css`.
2. Verifica que no arrastras caché. Para eliminarlo, [aquí tienes](https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/limpia-la-cache-y-elimina-los-archivos-temporales-) los pasos para hacerlo en **Firefox**, [aquí](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es) para hacerlo en **Chrome** y [aquí](https://www.frc.utn.edu.ar/ayuda/default.frc?i=38&t=1) tanto para **Opera** como **Safari**.